# Batch File: Users Input Path

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I need to get users input for the path my script have to read and create users form a txt file and i can't get it right i have tried SETX PATH but i didn't make any progress. So far i have this:

```
SETX /m PATH = Path of the file: 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in %PATH% do (
net user %%a 1234 /add 
)
```

The error i get is: Programma is unexpected at this time.

And i use SET /P the file just opens.

```
SET /p PATH = Path of the file: 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in "%path% do (
net user %%a 1234 /add /
)
```

Comment: `%PATH%` is already a system variable. Changing it is generally considered a bad idea, unless you're simply appending to it, which you aren't doing here. I recommend changing the variable name.

Comment: what are you trying to do? anyway, some suggestions: (1) Review the syntax or the `FOR` (read `HELP FOR`) and adjust your code accordingly. (2) don't use SETX, but SET; (3) don't use PATH, choose another name.

Comment: Also, `SET /p PATH = Path of the file:` sets a variable named "`PATH `" (PATH with a space after it). Remove the space before the `=` sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `PATH` is unnecessary (and will probably prevent net.exe from being found). There's no need to set an environment variable merely to access one data file.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (C:\path\to\file) do (
    net user "%%a" 1234 /add 
)
```

I added `delims=` and quoted `%%a` in case the user name has spaces in it.

`setx.exe` will modify the system environment, but (ironically) won't modify the environment of the running CMD process. If you wanted to modify PATH in the current environment, you'd have to use the CMD builtin `SET` (e.g. `SET "PATH=%PATH%;C:\usefuldir\bin"`). In the case you've given, though, changing the `PATH` won't help you at all.